# python - how to put values in a word length histogram

Tags: python

i want to put values at y-axis in the histogram i made.
I want every 100 values for example to put  "100-|" , "200-|" etc.
My code is:

```
def histogram(lenghts):
    xmax=max(lengths.keys())
    ymax=max(lenght.values())
    symbol=""
    indexing=""

    for j in range(ymax,-1,-10):
            symbol="{0}".format("|")
        for v in range(ymax,-1,-100):#here i try to put the values
            print("{0}{1:<4}".format(v,"-|"))

    #fill histogram
        for i in range(1,xmax):
            if i in lengths.keys() and lengths[i]>=j:
                symbol+="***"
            else:
                symbol+="   "
        print(symbol)

    #x-axis
    symbol="{:>5}".format("-+-")
    for i in range(1,xmax):
        symbol+="+--"
    print(symbol)

    #indexing x-axis
    for i in range(1,xmax):
        indexing+="{:>6}".format(i)
    print(indexing)

    return
```

I am getting values but only the same values ,for example "67-| , 167-| ,267-|".
I can't figure how to do it right!

Comment: you are constructing a string but you do nothing with it. if you insert a print statement you see what is going on !

Comment: It doesn't need a print statement.But also with print it prints nothing.

Comment: Sorry,it needs print ,but still nothing

Comment: Then use the python debugger to step into the code and look what is going on. http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a working code. The trick is in the module operator that is used to draw the scale number of the y axis when the y axis is a number close to a hundred.
There were some other minor problems in your code with the variable names.

```
def histogram(lenghts):
    xmax = max(lenghts.keys())
    ymax = max(lenghts.values())
    symbol = ""
    indexing = ""

    step = 10
    for j in range(ymax, -1, -step):
        if j % 100 < step:
            symbol = "{0:>3}{1:>3}".format(j, "-|")
        else:
            symbol = "{0:>3}{1:>3}".format(" ", "|")

        #fill histogram
        for i in range(1, xmax+1):
            if i in lenghts.keys() and lenghts[i] >= j:
                symbol += "***"
            else:
                symbol += "   "
        print(symbol)

    #x-axis
    symbol= "{0:>8}".format("-+--")
    for i in range(1, xmax+1):
        symbol += "+--"
    print(symbol)

    #indexing x-axis
    indexing = "    "
    for i in range(1, xmax+1):
        indexing += "{0:>3}".format(i)
    print(indexing)


lenghts = {4:104, 6:257, 10:157}
histogram(lenghts)
```

[image]

Comment: :Thanks!I am close.How can i put the increment number (100,200..)  every 5 "|". And why it begins from 7?

Comment: Because you are drawing using ymax as the starting range and moving every ten. As ymax is 257 (my numbers) it starts from there: 257-247-237-etc. With this kind of drawing you can not get 1 unit precision, so you could round the y axis numbers: 107 -> 100. Currently the position of 107 is only more or less 107 with an error of 10....so... vote and play with it. It is your turn to learn

Comment: Ok,but i told you because if i try (ymax,0,-5) it doesn't have a step of 5 "|".It messes.Thank you for your help

Comment: It works for me also with -5. Just now you need also to modify the catching line. Look at the modification of the code. Edit: Sorry, I understand now: you want hundred every five '|'. For these you have to use a higher step: 100 / 5 = 20